# Hide page elements without deactivating their events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a simple HTML/JS/Jquery game where you are supposed to look for a hidden vegetable on the page.

I have an image placed on the screen randomly on page load but it is hidden. When the user clicks on the image I want it to appear.

I tried using Jquery hide/show. This works fine if the image starts visible however, it fires the onclick event nicely. If the image starts as hidden it deactivates the onclick event. I know I am clicking on the correct spot on the page but the event never fires.

I tried using `$("#image").css("display", "none");`however this also deactivates the onclick. Is there another means of hiding an element that does not deactivate it's events?

Comment: Did you try `$("#image").css('visibility', 'hidden');` ?

Comment: Just tried. Also deactivates the onclick

Comment: What about using `opacity: 0` ?

Comment: Wow, great idea. It worked!

Comment: You can write an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: Ok I will, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `$("#image").css("opacity", "0");`

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#image").hide();
    )};
```

when u return to show

```
$("#image").show();
```

or

```
$("#image").style("opacity", "0");
```